# Elastic query to match any of provided conditions in BoolQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticjs

I made elastic.js build dynamic query like this:

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "term": { "tag": { "term": "rocket" } } },
                { "term": { "name": { "term": "space" } } }
            ],
            "should": [
                { "wildcard": { "place": { "value": "Moo*" } } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Elastic.js code for this is ( [Translator](http://docs.fullscale.co/translator/) ):

```
ejs.Request()
    .size(15)
    .query(
      ejs.BoolQuery()
        .must(ejs.TermQuery('tag', 'rocket'))
        .must(ejs.TermQuery('name', 'space'))
        .should(ejs.WildcardQuery('place', 'Moo*'))
)
```

It works great, I am happy and I would like it to be like that. *But* I realized that I need to add an option to perform this query with `OR` condition, instead of `AND` as is now.

It should find documents that match **any** of provided conditions.

And that task leaves me with no clues (even about DSL that will complete this purpose).

I have looked at [OrFilter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/or-filter/) but I have no idea on how to use it right (especially with elasticJS). Any solid source of information on elastic/js will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't you just put all clauses in the should section? That would become an OR then...

Comment: Excellent (I'm not the only one). It's exactly the way I've done it for now - guessed it yesterday. I wonder is it really the right way to go?

Comment: Yes it is. Why not? ;) I added my comment as a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your clauses in the should section of your [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/).

Regarding [elastic.js](http://www.fullscale.co/elasticjs/) I personally think it's a great piece of software, really well documented as well. Have a look at its [API documentation](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = ejs.Request({indices: index, types: type}),
    boolQ = ejs.BoolQuery();

boolQ.should(ejs.FieldQuery("DEAL_NAME","value")).defaultOperator("AND"));
boolQ.should(ejs.TermQuery( "DEAL_MOTTO","value"));                     
boolQ.should(ejs.FieldQuery("dealaddresses.CITY","value").defaultOperator("AND"));

r.query(boolQ);
```